# Bridged Networking with 64 bit Ubuntu 12.04 server as host to a KVM virtualized setup

Tags: 12.04, server, networking, 64-bit, kvm-virtualization

I saw two other similar posts on this topic but my situation is slightly different. Basically, I need to set up bridged networking that uses static ip (not dhcp) on an Ubuntu 12.04 host running KVM. I'm pretty new to this area of things and have seen a couple tutorials; but, what I've seen so far is pretty old stuff.

I did create an /etc/network/interfaces file for that purpose which can be seen here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1020623/

Problem is, it breaks name resolution on the host when I configure that setup on the system. Someone pointed out a step in a tutorial I was using that I had completely missed:

[Quote]3. After removing NetworkManager, edit /etc/resolv.conf and add in your nameserver.

nameserver 192.168.0.1[/Quote]

When I do a "less /etc/resolv.conf" the contents of the file indicate that it is not to be edited by hand. That any changes made to the file will be overwritten later.

Can someone outline the way to set up bridged networking with static ip with 64 bit Ubuntu 12.04 server?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I'll will try to help you.

> 1. After removing NetworkManager, edit /etc/resolv.conf and add in your nameserver. nameserver 192.168.0.1

This means that, as you disabled NetworkManager, you will need to take care of the /etc/resolv.conf yourself. AFAIK this message on the /etc/resolv.conf is there because NetworkManager put it there, or something else put it there. If you're not using any kind of dhcp, You should not expect this file to be modified. I wouldn't care about this warning in your case.

The '192.168.0.1' should be your router's ip or the dns ip provided by your ISP. To test your DNS server before put in this file, you can use the nslookup command like that:

```
nslookup somedomain.com 192.168.0.1
```

Where 192.168.0.1 is your expected DNS server.

Comment: Thanks. It is possible there is some dhcp configured (with my router possibly) but I'm not certain how to check that or what to do about it if it is.

Comment: Update: I'm not sure how useful this may be but I just found a web page describing changes to the way Ubuntu 12.04 handles some networking. It mentions changes to the way resolv.conf is managed (among other things) and claims "significant" changes from the way things were done in the past. http://www.stgraber.org/2012/02/24/dns-in-ubuntu-12-04/

Comment: By the way though going ahead and just editing /etc/resolv.conf manually did work. The system works fine now. Just that, after reading the information at the link (above), it occurs to me; that, while it may work, it may not be the 'proper' way any longer. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Note the response to the third comment in the comments section of that linked page. The third comment was written by Marius Gedminas but the reply to it may explain why/how editing /etc/resolv.conf still works.